# Clear cookies and cache from site

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, client, browser-cache, cache-control

Every time i update my website system UI/Jquery,
users complain that things are not working for them and that they have bugs.
Users are internet/computer dummies so they don't know how to clear the cookies or the cache of the browser, so i need to connect to each one of their computers and do it myself.
I spend lots off hours doing it and they always complain.

Some of the users use Chrome, some Firefox.
Googled and found no solution for this.
Is there any client code operation that will command the browser to clear its cache
or even pop up browser window which will ask user to confirm the clear?

Answer (score 0):

document.cookie = '';

With browsers that allow entering js code in the address bar you can simply make a shortcut lets say a favourite with the following code as a url:

```
javascript:document.cookie = '';
```

If you'd like to clear cache you can use meta tags not to cache the site, though caching is conciderable.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Comment: dont get me wrong...cache is good...it maked site work faster...but sometimes like after upload , I need to clear it

Answer (score 0):

Regarding cache clearing: No, there isn't.

What you can do, however, is configure your web server to correctly serve expiration and cache validity headers for your content. (How to do this depends on your web server.)

You can also use "cache busting" versioned URLs. Instead of using, let's say,

```
<script src="script.js">
```

you can "version" the URL like this:

```
<script src="script.js?2012-12-03-13-06">
<!-- or instead of dates any other versioning scheme you like -->
```

and when said script is updated, also increment/change the query parameter accordingly. This should cause browsers to consider the script as new as the URL isn't found in the cache.

Comment: are you sure...there are commands to add to favorite and save as homepage...there must be some other way